# How do I populate a span with an emoji or symbol based on the current width of the viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I want to have a span that will be populated by a specific emoji or symbol, for example: . The span will have the same width as the viewport. How many times the emoji will be displayed will be based on the current viewport width. How would I go about doing this?

Thank you so much.

HTML:

```
<div class="span__container">
  <span id="span-text"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.span__container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use images, you could set it as the background image:

```css
.span__container {
  background-image: url('/path/to/emoji.png'); // Use the url to the emoji
  background-size: 1em; // Set a size
  background-repeat: repeat-x; // Repeat only in horizontal direction
  height: 1em; // Needs the same height as the size
}
```

Comment: This is definitely easier than trying to calculate how many character-widths fit on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll give it a shot.